# Migrating to Sails.js 0.12 - middleware migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am migrating an old sails.js project which was written in 0.10.5 to 0.12.x.
Since the original code was written a long time ago and may have some "non-conforming" code I decided to re-build the project by starting a new sails project and slowly migrating the models/controllers/services while keeping only necessary policies and configuration files.

So far I managed to get the project to lift and now I am starting to deal with the authentication. Ideally, I intend to move to use passport with jwt to replace existing express-jwt.

My old config/http.js looks like so:

```
module.exports.http = {
    bodyParser: function() {
        //return require('body-parser')({limit: '900mb'});
        var opts = { limit:'50mb' };
        var fn;

        // Default to built-in bodyParser:
        fn = require('skipper');
        return fn(opts);
    },
    customMiddleware: function(app) {

        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var expressJwt = require('../libs/express-jwt');
        var experssJwtConfig = require('./jwt.js').jwt;

        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            next();
        });

        app.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: experssJwtConfig.secret}));

        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

        if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
            // just for local/development - serve static files      
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly (I am not well versed in the stack) this code overrides the default body parser (using skipper allowing large files - this is specified in `bodyParser`), and in addition, changes the middleware used:

- Includes a middleware to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
- For routes under 'api' it invokes the express-jwt middleware which in this implementation (not sure it's the default behavior) looks for the token and then add the user to the request object (which is then used in most of the controllers).
- Adds body parser's (`body-parser`) `json` and `urlencode` to the middleware chain.

My question here is whether I should keep it more or less the same or should I change it? Are there any obvious anti-patterns or security risks? If I use skipper, do I need the body parser json/urlencode middleware?

Would I be able to achieve comparable flows using more standard passport/jwt code? If so, can I achieve this kind of stack with `sails-auth` or should I role my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the custom middleware. Latest pattern is easier to manage. For starters,

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` can be set in `config/cors.js`
- You can use `passport-jwt` in a more *sailsy* way by making use of `sails-auth` module. And splitting the logic into `services`, using `policies` to manage the flow etc. The problem with `sails-auth` is, the module in npm has been published over an year ago. It has several bugs. The GitHub repo though has stable version.

I have made a bare minimum auth server in sails, which you can extend for various passport strategies. The server supports `local`, `bearer`, `JWT` strategies out of the box.

[Sails Auth Server](https://github.com/mjzac/SailsAuthServer)

Comment: Wow, that's quite comprehensive example - will take me a while to sort through it :-). I don't see sails-auth in package.js did you use it? From brief review, I am not sure how the passport is hooked up... Is there any resource that can help understand how all of this is working together?

Comment: The  `UserController.js`, `AuthController.js`, `Services/passport.js`, `Services/protocols` are all sails-auth files. Since module in npm  is outdated, i had to add it directly in the project.I can update the Readme if it helps.

Comment: I actually tried sails-auth but it seemed not to make any changes. If you can add to the readme a manual install steps or some additional how-to information that would be great...

Comment: This might help you. http://thenullpointer.in/2017/02/15/auth-server-using-sails.js-and-passport.js.html

Comment: Thanks - this link was helpful. I installed and run sails-auth and saw the "creation" of shadow model/controller/services which confused me since I need to somehow change the behavior... Adding the files manually means I will have to replace file on subsequent updates (which could be problematic if I implement custom behavior)... Maybe sails-auth is too opinionated for me and if it is not easily configurable (as opposed to re-coded) and not maintained - maybe not a best fit... in any case, thanks for the help!