# Sails.js middleware vs. policies

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am migrating a sails 0.10.5 (which was handed to me) to sails 0.12.x.

The application is more or less an API that is used by a mobile (cordova/hybrid) client.

As part of the migration, I want to rebuild some parts the proper sails way.

I've asked a question about middleware which is partially related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229717/migrating-to-sails-js-0-12-middleware-migration).

I am using passport for authentication (replacing old AuthController code) and now I am implemented JWT (choose not to use sails-auth for now).

From what I've seen, in most cases, people use passport-JWT to authenticate/check if there is a valid token through a **policy**.

In the previous implementation, (expressJwt) **middleware** was used to "inject" the user into the request and `req.user` is used in almost all my controller methods and is relied on in some of the existing policies.

Taking policy-based approach will require (almost) all of my routes to have a `isAuthenticated` policy. This means that if someone forget to put the policy, the controller may fail or worse, a non-authenticated user may access the route.

It is possible to use `*: 'isAuthenticated'` but since policies override and don't 'cascade', its possible for someone (who doesn't "knows the ropes") to do `somemethod: ['isThis','isThat']` without calling `isAuthenticated`, causing the same vulnerabilities.

The question is - should I use a policy-based approach or does adding a custom middleware to do the authentication and add the user to request (I guess like what passport.session does, more or less) makes sense here?

I am also using socket.io so does that changes something in favor of a policy-based or middleware-based approach? (I recall reading that "fake" socket routes are only passed through some of the middleware stack)

Answer (score -1):

**POLICIES**

Policies are supposed to be used for authentication. You should not use policies just to modify the request. It is ok to use them to modify the request if it is Auth related.

**MIDDLEWARE**

You should use middleware every time when you need to modify the request somehow(or response) but it is not anyhow auth related.

Comment: Other uses of policies:- Applying no-cache headers for one/multiple routes OR checking for whitelisting or blacklisting for a particular api endpoint OR Checking if user has solved the captcha to access an api. Tell me if I am doing it wrong?